# Powershell - Check if user with this SID Exist and remove his UPD

Tags: powershell, amazon-rds

Hello dear community.

We got MS RDS Terminal Server and we would like to remove User Profile Disks for deleted and (maybe) disabled users.

I would like one script with following tasks:

1. Get all UPDs from path
2. Check UPD Owner
3. Check if the owner exist in AD and if is enabled
4. Remove  UPD if owner not exist in ad or if is enabled

---

1. 

```
   $updtest = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\updtest -Force
```

2. 

```
    foreach($UPD in $updtest) {
##Get User Name
$UPD = $UPD.ToString()
$UPD = $UPD.Trim("UVHD-")
$UPD = $UPD.Trim(".vhdx")
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier `
    ($UPD)
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$userTest = $objUser.Value
$userTest = $userTest.Trim("Domain\")
```

3. $AdUser = [bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $userTest })

   if ($AdUser -eq $false) {Write-Host "User $userTest exist"}
   else  {Write-Host "User $AdUser exist"}

In step no. 3 is getting harder, because some users are not right trimmed (first letter missing). $UPD and $userTest have to be trimmed because Get-ADUser don't accept  "DOMAIN" and New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier don't accept ".vhdx" and "UVHD-"

Is there any another possibility to do easier this tasks?
It is possible to check if SID exists in AD without any conversion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `t is possible to check if SID exists in AD without any conversion?` - If you are using Get-ADUser the `-Identity` property accepts the SID as a value.

Comment: Thank you. How may I put it in this line? 
$AdUser = [bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $SID })

Comment: `$ADUser = $null -eq (Get-ADUser -Identity $SID)` - should be fine. You don't need to filter. Please see the docs - [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: Thank you! I tried your line, but $ADUser is always "False" `$updtest = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\UPD-Test -Force  


$updexclude = @('UVHD-template.vhdx')  
$updtest = $updtest | Where {$updexclude -notcontains $_}  
#$updtest  


foreach($UPD in $updtest) {  <br>
$UPD = $UPD.ToString()
$SID = $UPD.Trim("UVHD-")
$SID = $SID.Trim(".vhdx")
$SID


$ADUser = $null -eq (Get-ADUser -Identity $SID)
$ADUser

}`